# Android Large Scale Project - Is it ok to divide in to several library projects?

Tags: android, android-library

Im going to develop a very large scale android project, which has thousands of classes and resources. Im planning to separate application in to modules and develop them separately as library projects. Later combine them together. (Application may contain 5 - 6 modules, so planning to create 5 - 6 library projects and combine them)

Is this approach ok? or android experts, please suggest a way to maintain and develop such a big project?

**Edit:**

Libraries hold shared code for multiple applications -> Yes agreed 100% true

But this project is like combination of several projects.
Its like this:

Home Screen Dashboard has 8 buttons which represents 8 modules
you click on one button - > it opens up an activity and it has its own thousands of fragments, layouts, drawables etc, which is independent from other modules

so likewise i have non interdependent use cases which can be separated easily, and 4 - 5 developers are going to be involved this project, so if I can separate in to several library projects, i can simply allocate developers easily based on modules(library projects)

So one approach is to create one project and create package structure by modules
com.name.something.Module1

under this package i have

```
com.name.something.Module1.activity
com.name.something.Module1.util
com.name.something.Module1.widget
com.name.something.Module1.data
com.name.something.Module1.dao
```

and module 2

```
com.name.something.Module2

com.name.something.Module2.activity
com.name.something.Module2.util
com.name.something.Module2.widget
```

etc.

so this is first approach but each module has thousands of classes and resources, layout xml files etc.

The other approach is to separate modules as library projects.
I dont know how large scale projects maintain their codebase, like facebook, twitter etc.

Please advise.

Comment: Hi, I facing this problem and I need to serve some solutions for my team. did you acquired any proper approach to easing your life after two years later?

Comment: Hi, what I've done was, divide the whole application in to few layers, one library project as the core framework, one library project for data layer, one library project for service/business logic layer and another for presentation layer. Then incorporate bunch of libraries to reduce boilerplate code, mainly http://androidannotations.org/

Comment: I did the same as yours, used Gradle to combine all the projects. while compiling & packing however, the bunch of libraries must compiling & packing accordingly. therefore that just separated the project as pieces to make us focusing fewer codes, it never decrease the building time during developing. If every time we must waiting half minute or more then see our device come up the first window of our application, it would be boring to developing. are you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Libraries hold shared code for multiple applications... if you are entirely focused on a single application then there's no point in separating your code into 5-6 library projects.

One common way Android developers separate their project is by making sub-packages for different components. For example, custom `View`s and adapter's go in `com.package.name.ui`, utility packages go in `com.package.name.util`, etc. Other than that, you just have to be smart... starting an app from scratch that will have "thousands of classes" sounds pretty ambitious and there is not really any single piece of advice that will make your life easy.

Comment: Agreed.  There's no silver bullet for large application development.  Developing separate libraries can have a couple minor pain points (particularly around unit testing), but there's no significant cost or benefit.

Comment: I take that back.  It can compile slightly faster with separate libraries because not everything needs to be recompiled.  But I highly doubt the speed differences are worth it.

Comment: Agreed both of you, please see the question, i have modified it, please comment..

Answer (score 1):

Is each module separated from each other or do they share data (e.g. the same database)? If they are separated I would suggest to create 8 separate apps, which would reduce the memory footprint of your app and would improve launch time.

If some, or all are using the same database, you might be able to create a database on the SD-card and use it from each separate app.